# I keep having to lower my weights by a couple Pounds on each set. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: workout, weights

When my work out begins, I normally begin strong. For example, I can lift up to 30 Lbs doing bicep curls, I can feel the burn, but it's not difficult at all to do the curls in good form; but as the workout progresses, I find myself having to lower my weights in each set. For example, by the second set of bicep curls, I have to lower the weights to 27 Lbs to maintain good form. By the third set I'm doing 25 Lbs, and so on.

It's not that I start feeling tired, low energy or anything, it's just that my muscles simply can't take it. What am I doing wrong? I was hoping I could maintain the same number of pounds throughout the entire workout. What do I need to change? Should I start with lower weights even though they'll feel too light?

Comment: Is just that your metabolic capabilities are not at the point where you can repeat the same performance with the amount of rest you're taking. To use simpler words, just rest longer for now.

Answer (score 1):

A good warmup is very important, when it comes to a good workout. Many lifers I know don't like the idea of warmup, but it's a way to get your body prepared for what coming next. Make sure you start with good warmup before you even think of lifting.

Secondly, if 30 lbs is the max that you can curl, then don't go for 30 in the first set. First set should be something light for you(may vary for experienced lifters) to pump the blood to the muscles and get them ready. Gradually keep on increasing till you reach your peak, then do drop weights.

Lifting heavy right from the word go, would not only hamper the form, but lead to injuries as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @xCodeZone's answer, consider resting longer (for example, three to five minutes or more) between each set.  When training for strength, it's more important to complete your repetitions in each set than to complete sets with fewer repetitions, and/or less weight.